# How to make appear that the computer in different networks have same IP address?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ip

I am using a dongle on my laptop and mobile internet on my phone to access my account at same time. The site I am trying to access allows just one login at a time and as the IP address on two devices is different I am repeatedly logged from one or other device repeatedly and my work is lost.

So I just thought if I can some way make the other computer on the different network to have IP address same as my pc then I will be able to log in at the same time without repeated logouts. 
I don't know if it is possible.
So if it is possible then can someone guide me through the right way to tackle the issue.

If the idea that I thought is not practical but if there is some other way to tackle the issue I am facing, then even that answer is excepted.

If the idea is not practical but the problem can be solved through other means then I will make sure to change the title so that someone else will find it easy to search this question if they face same issue.

Thank you.

Comment: Even if you did do this client side, the server would know the truth, so you wouldn't accomplish very much.

Comment: So is there any way similar to giving remote access only difference being I don't want the same screen but same internet connection.@Ramhound

Comment: Remove access to what exactly  I thought you had a device with two adapters?

Comment: You could use your phone through the PC - if it has wifi you could [Turn Your PC Into a Wi-Fi Hotspot](https://www.howtogeek.com/214080/how-to-turn-your-windows-pc-into-a-wi-fi-hotspot/).

Comment: The login session is more than just the IP address, so you won't fool the server when faking a private IP address that the server's not seeing anyway. No go.